# Using variables (from user input) for lat/long with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Messing around with the Google Maps API in a browser, however I'm having a bit of trouble putting in a user input for the variables. Essentially, I want to be able to put in a new lat/long from pressing a button on the page and have the map move onto that.

It doesn't work for the actual input variables, but when I use the commented out section it works perfectly fine.

```
    <body>
    <form id = "input" method = "get">
        <input type = "text" placeholder = "Latitude" name = "user_lat">
        <input type = "text" placeholder = "Longitude" name = "user_lng"><br>
        <button type = "submit">Mark on Map</button>
    </form>
    <div id = "map"></div>
        <script>
            var lat_in = parseFloat($('#user_lat').val());
            var lng_in = parseFloat($('#user_lng').val());
            /*var lat_in = 37.697948;
            var lng_in = -97.314835;*/
            function initMap() {
                var location = {lat: lat_in, lng: lng_in};
                /*var location = {lat: 37.697948, lng: -97.314835};*/
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: location
                    });
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    map: map
                    });
            }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="link with the API key here">
    </script>
```

I suspect it might have something to do how I actual use the submit button and the way I interact with it, but I'm not 100% sure. I've looked up different things, but I'm still a bit new at this. I just started to dabble in javascript, so I'm sure there are better methods to do this, but I just want to get this working to get an understanding of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, Add change listener and on change pan to that location by clicking enter

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Directions service</title>
<style>
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   * element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #floating-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25%;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="floating-panel">
<b>Start: </b>
<input id="start" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter lat">
<b>End: </b>
 <input id="end" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter lng">
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: {lat: 0,  lng:  0}
    });

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:map,
                draggable:true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: {lat: 0,  lng:  0}
            });
    var onChangeHandler = function() {
      DisplayPoint(map);
    };
    //document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);


  function DisplayPoint(map) {

      var lat = document.getElementById('start').value;
      var lng = document.getElementById('end').value;
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      marker.setPosition(latLng);
      map.panTo(latLng);

  }
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: This one works exactly the way I was imagining it! Thank you!